# pkg-config error when compiling mongodb c++ v3 test code

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

Following this [guid](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/mongocxx-v3/installation/)

I ran into an error:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"
c++ --std=c++11 test.cc -o test $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libmongocxx)
c++: error: Symbol’s function definition is void: pkg-config: No such file or directory
```

What's $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libmongocxx), never use this? How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pkg-config](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) is a tool to locate headers and libraries and provide compiler flags for them.  It looks like you probably don't have it installed on your system.  Either install it, or remove the `pkg-config` stanza and specify your compiler flags manually based on where you installed mongocxx.

Comment: After restart my ArchLinux, no error output, the pkg-config works for me now. Thanks.